# Prove the inequality for composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, inequality, conjectures

> Is it true that $c_m+c_n$ $>$ $c_{m+n}$ for all $m$, $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$?

Though the result seems true, I can't get a solution. Even the bounds on $c_n$ obtained from Prime Number Theorem isn't helping me. Is there any way to prove it?

Comment: Could you define $c_n$?

Comment: Its not clear from the question but I guess that $c_{n}$ is $n^{\text{th}}$ composite number so that $c_{1} = 4, c_{2} = 6, c_{3} = 8, c_{4} = 9, \ldots$

Comment: I am extremely sorry that I forgot to define $c_n$. Yes, $c_n$ is the $n$-th composite.

Comment: You might find http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/027_01_JIPAM/027_01_www.pdf interesting.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That was very interesting indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: But the bounds in the paper isn't also helping to prove the problem. Is there really any solution to it?